# Fasted way to communicate between App Engine modules

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to deploy some modules on App Engine. For now I let them "talk" to each other by a simple REST api.
I wonder if is there any kind of "local address" to use instead of *.appspot.com public domain?

If nothing available, what is the fasted protocal/method to communicate between two modules not including sharing the same database and memcache?

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve? We are talking milliseconds here.

Comment: What @AndreiVolgin said, also that I'd venture to guess any API would just be an abstraction of HTTP requests anyway, given how App Engine works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *only* way to communicate between modules is via HTTP requests, synchronously via [URL Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) or async via [Push Queue API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push), which can only be done via `*.appspot.com` URLs. But this are always resolved to local IP address so inter-module communication always goes through internal AppEngine network.

Also, the official docs about [module communication](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Communication_between_modules) uses [`ModuleService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService) API which resolves module addresses to `*.appspot.com` addresses, so this is an official google way of addressing modules.

You can share data between modules via datasore/memcache but I don't consider this *communication* as it does not actively notify receiving party about the data.